# Hibernate, Generics, Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<T>

Tags: java, hibernate

```
private static Session session;
...
public <T> List<T> getObject(String query) {
    List<T> list = (List<T>)session.createQuery(query).list();
    return list;
}
```

I don't want to use "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")"
How to modify that method, to receive universal method which can receive any List<> ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around it. You can't avoid a warning when casting a raw list to a generic list, since the compiler has no way to check that elements of the raw list are indeed T instances.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not support generics in its API. So short answer is: "there is no way around this".

You could use the JPA API (which Hibernate implements) where generics are supported.